# How to get media path from magento backend

Tags: template, backend, admin-panel, magento2.4.3

I want to get the media URL from the Magento backend template. Can anyone guide me to sort out this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this, i hope it helps you.

$mediaUrl =$storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);